# not ... so are/is

Tags: grammar, negation

I left a comment [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/38766/meaning-of-vague-that-up/38776#), and I wanted to use the grammatical construction that uses "s" below.

> yes; I'm a learner, but **not** all learners *are* the same and **so are** the
>   native speakers.

Was that correct? I mean what comes before "so are" was negative, and I wanted to say that what is true (positive or negative) for learners is also true for natives.

Comment: No, it's not. Because of the preceding negation ***but not***, you need ***and nor are***. Thus *"A is true and **so** is B"*, but *"A is **not** true and **nor** is B"*.

Comment: [not...neither, not...nor](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/102714/2637) - same difference. Maybe some people only ever use one version, but I suspect most people use both freely.

Comment: You are missing a verb: "... not all learners **are** the same ...".

Comment: Thanks tunny. 'tis fixed! @FumbleFingers I've learned a lot from you, thank you.

Comment: Still, this is a good question. The sentence "not all learners are the same" is not the same as "all learners are not the same". The latter means all learners are different, the first one does not! The latter would _obviously_ warrant a _nor_ construction, but the former only on semantic grounds, I think.

Comment: @oerkelens: I think you're mistaken. *"All X's are not the same"* implies *"**Some** X's are different to **some** other X's"*. It does *not* imply that *"**Every** X is different to **every** other X"*.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't make sense. "So are" means you wish to attribute a quality that one object had to another object. There is no quality that you're attributing here. You're only saying that they're not all the same. This *could* be expressed like so:

> Yes, I'm a learner, but us learners are all different and so are the native speakers.

Here, I'm attributing **different** to both learners and native speakers.

Like FumbleFingers stated, this also violates parallelism. Parallelism is the grammatical concept of making certain that elements of your sentence structure are consistent. It's quite broad and encompasses several rules, but this is one of them; because of the previous negation, "so are" must also be negated. You must change your diction and meaning to fit this structure (or find a way to write it with no negatives, like I did above).

Comment: "learners are all different" does not mean the same as "not all learners are the same". It may be nuance, but still.

Comment: @oerkelens Hence "could."